# How to calculate the intersection using formulas?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I have two six-sided dice and I need to calculate the probability of achieving the following two scenarios.

1. The sum of the dice is greater than or equal to 7 which is 7/12
2. The second die is a 3 which is 1/6

The problem is calculating the intersection of 1 and 2. P(1 intersection 2), I know if you count the sample space, it's 1/12.

I've also checked that the 1 and 2 are not independent of each other - P(1) *P(2) != P(1intersection 2)

But how do I use the formula to calculate intersection without needing to count the sample space?

Comment: Which formula you want to use exactly?

Comment: You could use $P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to count the sample space in some way or another. But there are ways so that you don't have to count the sample space of $36$, but rather a sample space of six two times.

The relevant formula is
$$
P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B\mid A)
$$
Let $A$ be your 2. and $B$ be your 1, and you should be able to get the answer very quickly compared to how you did it, as each of the factors have a sample space of just $6$.